# Emacs ElDoc interfere Evil search

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I use Emacs with Evil mode, and while I entering the search pattern, the ElDoc message is displayed replace the current search pattern. It is quite annoying. I looked into ElDoc and see a function `eldoc-display-message-p` that check for conditions that ElDoc should not display the message.

I need some hint to advice this function to prevent ElDoc interference with Evil search.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, can you provide additional information? When I position my cursor in a place that should trigger eldoc then start a :/s/foo/bar the eldoc message is not displayed. what command are you using? And what kind of source / eldoc are you using?


A possible solution may be to include (active-minibuffer-window) inside the `eldoc-display-message-no-interference-p` condition. So eldoc won't display if there is an active minibuffer

Comment: @JordonBiondo The problem occurred when searching with `/something`, and not Evil-ex. I tried including `(active-minibuffer-window)`, but it still the same. Thanks.

Comment: What eldoc implementation are you using? What code are you editing? This may make a big difference especially if your eldoc function is going out to an external process for information. Another possible solution is to check if `isearch-mode` is non-nil inside `eldoc-display-message-no-interference-p`, Searching in evil uses isearch so that variable will be non-nil in your buffer while you are searching.

Comment: It happened to all of the mode I'm editing. Checking for `isearch-mode` in `eldoc-display-message-no-interference-p` solved the problem though. Could you please post an answer so I can approve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `eldoc-display-message-no-interference-p` is a predicate function that will determine whether or not to display an eldoc message at the time.

Searching in Evil uses isearch, so when you are searching, the variable `isearch-mode` will be non nil.

You can customize the behavior of `eldoc-display-message-no-interference-p` by editing it directly but that is often not the best choice, we can modify it's behavior instead by using "after advice". [If you are unfamiliar with advice, read about it here.](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Advice.html)

```
(defadvice eldoc-display-message-no-interference-p (after dont-show-when-isearching activate)
  "Always return nil if isearch-mode is active."
  (setq ad-return-value (and ad-return-value (not isearch-mode))))
```